# Developing Polyframe image editing app for windows phone

Tags: image-processing, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Hi last week i started developing a polyframe application for windows phone 8. So for development i am using IOS PolyFrame app as a reference: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/polyframe/id481964944.

So what my doubt is, i need to implement a photo frame based on the structures provided. And the app will support adding / editing images in each layout and also changing the orientation of the selected layout. So my question is, is it possible to develop similar with xaml and C#. I am facing issues with filling images with the layouts and layout adjustment related things. Can any one suggest me some ideas to start developing application.

Comment: Provide some image in the Polyframe app in which you are trying the functionality.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e2g0owf71i6492/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, you should be able to do what you're trying to build using XAML.

Here's a VERY simple example of how you might apply an irregular mask over a photo:

[image: Cats]

This was achieved using the following XAML:

```
        <Image Source="/Assets/cat.jpg" Height="200"
                Clip="M 120 95 L 90 265 L 220 265 L 190 95 A 50 50 0 1 0 120 95" 
                Margin="0,10,224,0" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-50"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="/Assets/cat.jpg" Height="200"  
                Clip="M 120 95 L 90 265 L 220 265 L 190 95 A 50 50 0 1 0 120 95" 
                Margin="0">
            <Image.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection 
                                GlobalOffsetX="50" 
                                GlobalOffsetY="-190" 
                                RotationZ="45"/>
            </Image.Projection>
        </Image>
```

Note that you're going to have to either do some math or design some pre-computed regions to line everything up the way you want, but it looks entirely feasible to me.